# How to manage state of multiple radio option groups when mapped

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, radio-group

I want to be able to manage the state of radio groups which will be dynamically rendered.

The code below renders 2 sets of radio groups (could be more), and both groups states are managed by "const [delay, setDelay] = useState('accept');". I need each group's state to be managed separately.

```
const [delay, setDelay] = useState('accept');

...

{data.map(({ delayOwner }, index: number) => (
            <Tr key={index}>
              {delayOwner && (
                <Td>
                  <RadioOption
                    groupId={`radioDelay-${index}`}
                    label="Accept"
                    onChange={() => setDelay('accept')}
                    value={delay === 'accept'}
                  />
                  <RadioOption
                    groupId={`radioDelay-${index}`}
                    label="Reject"
                    onChange={() => setDelay('reject')}
                    value={delay === 'reject'}
                  />
                </Td>
              )}
```

The current output: if I select Accept/ Reject on the first radio group, the second radio group will also change.

```
* Accept O Reject
* Accept O Reject

* = selected, O = not selected
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You shouldn't be using radio buttons here. If they can both be selected at the same time, you should use checkboxes. Radio buttons are for selecting a single option out of several options, checkboxes are for selecting individual unrelated options. A select (dropdown) is for selecting one of many options when there are either too many options to show as radio buttons, or when it doesn't make sense to show radio buttons (such as a year selector).

Comment: There are actually 2 groups (or more) of radio options, so radio options are appropriate here; plus this is from the UX designs :)

Comment: Ahh I thought RadioOption was an individual radio button - my bad :).

Comment: NP, thanks for your input, I appreciate every suggestion. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use index with your state to keep it separate

```
{data.map(({ delayOwner }, index: number) => (
                            <Tr key={index}>
                                {delayOwner && (
                                    <Td>
                                        <RadioOption
                                            groupId={`radioDelay-${index}`}
                                            label="Accept"
                                            onChange={() => setDelay({...delay, index:"accept"})}
                                            value={delay[index] === 'accept'}
                                        />
                                        <RadioOption
                                            groupId={`radioDelay-${index}`}
                                            label="Reject"
                                            onChange={() => setDelay({...delay, index:"reject"})}
                                            value={delay[index] === 'reject'}
                                        />
                                    </Td>
                                )}
```

Comment: Hi iamwebkalakaar, thank you for the suggestion, I tried to implement it in the code, but I'm getting this typeScript error: "Spread types may only be created from object types. ts(2698)"

Answer (score 0):

If you need the states to be managed separately, then declare two states.

```
const [groupOneDelay, setGroupOneDelay] = useState('accept');
const [groupTwoDelay, setGroupTwoDelay] = useState('accept');
```

If the mapping is going to be a problem and this state isn't needed by anything else in this component/file, then you should probably move the state into another component and let that component handle the state individually.

Something like

```
export default function RadioOptionComponent() {
  const [delay, setDelay] = useState('accept');

  return (
    <div
      groupId={`radioDelay-${index}`}
      label="Accept"
      onChange={() => setDelay({...delay, index:"accept"})}
      value={delay[index] === 'accept'}
    />
  )
}
```

And then render that component.

Also see JMadelaine's comment because you should consider why you're using radio buttons here.

Comment: The radio groups are being mapped, so I'm not sure how I would put those in the <RadioOption/>

Comment: Sounds like you may need to create another component and let that component manage its own state then. Is there a reason the state has to be managed at this level where the mapping is happening?

Comment: It doesn't have to be managed at this level where the mapping happens; where would you suggest to manage it?

Comment: Sure thing, happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.